# Calculating Fibonacci numbers with Streams and BigInteger

Tags: java, algorithm, lambda, functional-programming, java-stream

I have the following is code for calculating the *Fibonacci number* at position `10`:

```
IntStream.range(1,10)
         .mapToObj(ignore ->     List.Of(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.One)
         .reduce(List.Of(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.One), (values,ignore) -> ???)
         .get(1)
```

How do I replace the question marks in the code?

I have to achieve it by using only functional programming.

Comment: `Stream.iterate(new BigInteger[] {BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE}, a -> new BigInteger[] {a[1], a[0].add(a[1])}).map(a -> a[0])`  yields an infinite stream of the Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 3):

The lambda you need is:

```
(values, ignore) -> List.of(values.get(1), values.get(0).add(values.get(1)))
```

which converts the list `[a, b]` to `[b, a+b]`.

However, There are some compile errors in your code:

- It's `List.of()` not `List.Of()`
- It's `BigInteger.ONE` not `BigInteger.One`

And a logic error: The [first fibonacci number is 0, not 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), so to return the nth fibonacci number by starting with `IntStream.range(1, n)`, the accumulator must be `List.of(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE)`, not `List.of(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE)`.

The full working code is then:

```
BigInteger fibonacci = IntStream.range(1, 10)
  .mapToObj(ignore -> List.of(BigInteger.ZERO))
  .reduce(
    List.of(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE),
    (values, ignore) -> List.of(values.get(1), values.get(0).add(values.get(1)))
  ).get(0);
```

which returns `34`, which is the 10th fibonacci number.

---

Rather than use `IntStream#range()`, a simpler way is to use [`Stream#generate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate(java.util.function.Supplier)) to generate the starting list and apply [`limit(n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit(long)), using the same lambda from above:

```
BigInteger fibonacci = Stream.generate(() -> List.of(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE))
  .limit(10)
  .reduce((values, ignore) -> List.of(values.get(1), values.get(0).add(values.get(1))))
  .get().get(0);
```

Also returning `34`.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko now that the discussion is over (and you got your accept tick), you should delete all your "discussion with new user" comments and flag all user's comments as "No longer needed", because they have no lasting value and aren't actually relevant to the question or helpful to anyone else. In general, comments like "Thanks", "Does this help?" and "Please accept my answer" and similar are conversational between two users and not useful to anyone else and are therefore targeted for immediate deletion. As for policing askers who don't accept etc - leave that alone too.

Comment: @alex in a nutshell, only make comments that are useful to *everybody*. Read [How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756) in its entirety. Don't demand action from people. The longest time between me posting an answer and it being accepted is about 8 years. This is a community help site. Your posts are still discoverable and will still help others whether it is upvoted/accepted or not. Some people don't follow through on their obligations, but most people behave well here, which is why this site is so helpful to so many. Stop worrying about unresponsive users.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to utilize this code for relatively small input numbers like `10`, usage of `BigInteger` doesn't seem to be justifiable.

Otherwise, creating a new list for every member of the sequence is harmful performance-wise. It'll be better to create a *list* just once and then ***reuse*** it.

Unfortunately `List.of()` returns an immutable *list*, and in order to make it mutable you have wrap it with an `ArrayList` and clumsy code becomes more clumsy...

Instead, I advise to make use of an array as shown below, it'll make the code both more performant and easier to reason about.

```
public static BigInteger getFib(int num) {

    return Stream.iterate(new BigInteger[]{BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE}, // the only array created in the stream
                          arr -> {arr[1] = arr[0].add(arr[1]);      // calculating the next member of the sequence
                                  arr[0] = arr[1].subtract(arr[0]); // calculating the previous member of the sequence
                                  return arr;})                     // returning the same array
            .limit(num - 1)
            .reduce((left, right) -> right)
            .map(arr -> arr[1])
            .orElse(BigInteger.ZERO);
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<BigInteger> result = // generating a list Fibonacci numbers for demo purposes
            IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10)
                    .mapToObj(num -> getFib(num))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

**Output**

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the `Nth` term of a fibonacci sequence you can do it like this. No list is involved as they are calculated on the fly and only the `Nth` one is printed or returned. This works by initializing an array `a` to `[ 0, 1 ]` and generating subsequent arrays of `[ a[1], a[0] + a[1] ]` such that `a[0]` is the used as the term in the series. Positions start at `1` which can be changed if insufficient.

- define the position (must be >= 1) or (i.e >= first position)
- using arrays iterate the series.
- skip the first `position - 1` terms in the stream.
- then print the next one (or assign it)

```
int position = 10;
Stream.iterate(new BigInteger[] { BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE },
        (a) -> new BigInteger[] { a[1], a[0].add(a[1]) })
        .skip(position-1).limit(1)
        .map(a->a[0]).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

prints

```
34
```

to assign it change `forEach` to `findFirst().get().` and assign to a `BigInteger`.

Here I've included that in a method.

```
public static BigInteger getFibTerm(int position) {
    if (position < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("position must be >= 1");
    }
    return Stream.iterate(
            new BigInteger[] { BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE },
            (a) -> new BigInteger[] { a[1], a[0].add(a[1]) })
            .skip(position - 1).limit(1).map(a -> a[0])
            .findFirst().get();
}
```